# Opera-like tab-switching in chrome or firefox

Tags: firefox, mouse, google-chrome, opera, mouse-scroll

Is there a way of switching tabs in Chrome or Firefox by scrolling the mouse-wheel while keeping the right mouse-button pressed?

In Chrome or Firefox (with tab-wheel-scroll extension) you can switch tabs by scrolling the wheel while hovering the pointer over the tab-bar.

The Opera function is much more comfortable, since you don't have to aim at the tab-bar in order to switch.

I have already tried assigning tab-switching keyboard shortcuts to the mouse-button in combination with the mouse-wheel, but it did not work at all. It seems to me that mouse-events cannot be combined in xbindkeys. Furthermore, assigning anything to the right mouse-button in xbindkeys disabled the standard functions of the button completely.

Thanks in advance, bye 
YSN

Comment: I've also greatly missed Opera's mouse gestures now that I primarily use Chrome.  There are a few extensions for some of the functionality, but they tend to not work as well or don't do everything. :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [FireGestures](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6366/) extension. What you want is in "Advanced >> Wheel Gestures". It does exactly that. There is no need to point the mouse over the tabs.

Comment: Great solution for firefox, thanks! I'm afraid, an extension will not be able to handle that task in chrome flawlessly, since extensions are disabled for the main tab there. Maybe a global keybinding solution could work.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome I use Smooth Gestures.
https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/lfkgmnnajiljnolcgolmmgnecgldgeld
You can simply create gestures as you want I really like it.
For tab browsing in Chrome I use Quick Tab
https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/bdeifmcaonlafkglbdpbbhkeecjnkipo?hl=en
It is not like the ctrl+tab function in Opera but it much more comfortable than the built in one 
But give a try to Opera 11 ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can switch tabs in Chrome by scrolling the mouse wheel while keeping the mouse arrow over the tabs line. This is a default behavior not an extension

Comment: The OP does already mention that.

Comment: is mentioning using an extension. I get this behavior without extensions.